# Creating dictionary from list of lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I am working on an online course exercise (practice problem before the final test).

The test involves working with a big csv file (not downloadable) and answering questions about the dataset. You're expected to write code to get the answers.
The data set is a list of all documented baby names each year, along with
#how often each name was used for boys and for girls.
A sample list of the first 10 lines is also given:

```
Isabella,42567,Girl
Sophia,42261,Girl
Jacob,42164,Boy
```

and so on.

Questions you're asked include things like 'how many names in the data set', 'how many boys' names beginning with z' etc.

I can get all the data into a list of lists:

```
[['Isabella', '42567', 'Girl'], ['Sophia', '42261', 'Girl'], ['Jacob', '42164', 'Boy']]
```

My plan was to convert into a dictionary, as that would probably be easier for answering some of the other questions. The list of lists is saved to the variable 'data':

```
names = {}
for d in data:
    names[d[0]] = d[1:]

print(names)
{'Isabella': ['42567', 'Girl'], 'Sophia': ['42261', 'Girl'], 'Jacob': ['42164', 'Boy']}
```

Works perfectly.

Here's where it gets weird. If instead of opening the sample file with 10 lines, I open the real csv file, with around 16,000 lines. everything works perfectly right up to the very last bit.
I get the complete list of lists, but when I go to create the dictionary, it breaks - here I'm just showing the first three items, but the full 16000 lines are all wrong in a similar way):

```
names = {}
for d in data:
    names[d[0]] = d[1:]

print(names)
{'Isabella': ['56', 'Boy'], 'Sophia': ['48', 'Boy'], 'Jacob': ['49', 'Girl']
```

I know the data is there and correct, since I can read it directly:

```
for d in data:
    print(d[0], d[1], d[2])

Isabella 42567 Girl
Sophia 42261 Girl
Jacob 42164 Boy
```

Why would this dictionary work fine with the cvs file with 10 lines, but completely break with the full file? I can't find any

Comment: Maybe there are some boys named "Isabella". Each key in the dictionary should be unique.

Comment: It sounds like there may be duplicate names in the file, so you can't use them as the key in a dictionary, unless you make the values 2-dimensional lists.

Comment: You could also take only the most common form of every name

Comment: You could use 2 different dictionaries for boys and girls

Comment: ooooh - ok, it never occurred to me that Isabella could be a boy's name. Let me check the data set...

Comment: if there was something like `[[['Isabella', '55', 'Girl']], [['Isabella', '56', 'Boy']]]` then it would show up as `'Isabella': ['56', 'Boy']`

Comment: In your `for` loop, you're assuming that the key `d[0]` is not present in the `names` dict. So, assert that in your code explicitly, to catch situations where the data doesn't match your expectations. For example: `if d[0] in names: raise Exception(f"Duplicate name: {d[0]}")`

Comment: OK, there were indeed 42567 girls names Isabella....and 56 boys named Isabella.

Debating the best way forward; simply creating two dictionaries seems easy enough, unless anyone has any other ideas.

How can I credit the first person to note the possibility of duplicates with the answer?

Comment: Creating two dictionaries won't solve the problem, you'll still merge all the girls named Isabella into a single dictionary item.

Comment: Why do you think you should convert it into a dictionary in the first place? There's no unique key for any of the data. Just keep it as a list and count the things you need for each query?

Comment: Or if you're allowed to use libraries, Pandas is the appropriate tool for processing data like this.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the comments to create two dicts, or a single dictionary with tuple keys. Using tuples as keys is fine if you keep your variables inside python, but you might get into trouble when exporting to json for example.

Try a dictionary comprehension with list unpacking

```py
names = {(name, sex): freq for name, freq, sex in data}
```

Or a for loop as you started

```py
names = dict()
for name, freq, sex in data:
    names[(name, freq)] = freq
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with something like

```py
results = {}
for d in data:
    name, amount, gender = d.split(',')
    results[name] = data.get(name, {})
    results[name].update({ gender: amount })
```

this way you'll get results in smth like

```
{
    'Isabella': {'Girl': '42567', 'Boy': '67'}, 
    'Sophia': {'Girl': '42261'}, 
    'Jacob': {'Boy': '42164'}
}
```

However duplicated values will override previous, so you need to take that into account if there are some and it also assumes that the whole file matches format you've provided